# What prevent a smartphone wallet from downloading my keys

Tags: wallet, private-key, mnemonic-seed

Wallet software use variant technologies to protect and hide our private keys like mnemonic or simply using the private keys.

What would prevent them from making a patch to their software that will install a keylogger, making a screenshoot, or simply going into the memory and retrieving those private informations ?

Comment: You are always at the mercy of your software ... Not just in bitcoin wallets. AKA *malware*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.

A Bitcoin wallet that is online and connected in some way to the Internet is referred to as **hot wallet**.

That is why it is recommended to keep as much money as you would put in your pocket in a hot wallet.